# Unable to view flask app on reserved static address on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, deployment, flask-sqlalchemy

Instead of the usual way of deployment via Gcloud command line, I simply sshed the GCP Ubuntu instance and deployed my flask app via WinSCP by transferring the files onto the Ubuntu instance I have created. I was able to get it to run like so:

[image: Flask server]

I have also reserved a static address so that I could allow users to view the Flask app.

However, when I tried to access the external ip address, GCP refused to connect and I can't view my flask app.

What could I have possibly done wrong?

Comment: Did you open `8080` port on both GCP and Ubuntu?

Comment: What are your firewall rules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no VPC Firewall rule to allow ingress traffic to your instance on tcp/8080.

**First step:** Add a network tag on your GCE instance, `allow-8080-ingress`.

**Second step:** Under the web menu, go to `VPC Network` - `Firewall` - `Create Firewall Rule` and create a new rule with following properties:

- **Name:** Whatever8080
- **Network:** [select the network to whom your instance belongs to]
- **Direction of traffic:** Ingress
- **Action on match:** Allow
- **Targets:** Specified target tags
- **Target Tags:** allow-8080-ingress (the network tag that you added on your instance)
- **Source filter:** IP ranges
- **Source IP ranges:** 0.0.0.0/0 <<== This will allow incoming traffic from any IP. You may be more specific, choosing a smaller range or even a specific IP address.
- **Specified protocols and ports:** Check tcp and add 8080

You did not attached the your flask code, but if you launch it like this, it will just work:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':     
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

...being able to access it by the public IP:

[image]

Comment: Also on Ubuntu, you should allow incoming ports to `8080` by typing `sudo ufw allow 8080/tcp` in your Terminal.

Comment: You might be right. I am testing now. It depends on the template image used. Will update the answer if true. Thanks for pointing this.

Comment: Hey @RezaBehzadpour. I reproduced. No need to open 8080 in iptables. `if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)` did the job. I attached screen-shot in answer

Comment: Good job @NeoAnderson.