# Unable to run Flask app on Google Cloud server

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, firewall

I want to run a flask webpage on google cloud server. The html and other related files are on the server, not local. I created a firewall rule with

1. Name allow-http-5000
2. Direction ingress
3. Target tags "name of instance"
4. IP range 0.0.0.0/0
5. Protocol and port tcp:5000

After running the python file I open http://ExternalIP:5000, but it is showing me the error "This site can't be reached".

I entered ExternalIP as the one mentioned as "External IP address" on the Network interface details of the instance.

I would be grateful for any help on this.

Edit:

1. Output of curl http://localhost:5000/.

"curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 5000: Connection refused"

2. Inside Flask code

`if __name__ == '__main__':`

```
`app.run(debug=False, port=5000, host='0.0.0.0')`
```

3. Flask output
   [image]

Comment: From inside the same system running your Flask app, try `curl http://localhost:5000/`. What is the result? Which IP address are you setting up the Flask HTTP server with (localhost or 0.0.0.0)? Edit your post and show your Flask code and add these details.

Comment: The output from curl means that your Flask app is not running (listing on port 5000). Are there any other messages when you start your app?

Comment: How are you running this code and what is the filename? You are leaving out important details. Edit your post and provide more information.

Comment: I added an image showing the Flask output. I am running it with python3 command.

Comment: You tagged this ```google-app-engine```. Are you actually running this on GAE? If you're using GAE and want to quickly get a simple flask up and running, then you don't need Firewall rules, tags and the other stuff you listed. See [sample app](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/main/appengine/standard_python3/hello_world) from Google

Comment: @NoCommandLine Sorry, I tagged wrongly. I am not running it on google-app-engine, currently I am running it on google compute engine. The flask webpage has some has data input from kafka and MongoDB. I am not sure if that would be possible on google-app-engine

Comment: Thank you for your help, it is working, I added the network tag correctly as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63069696/unable-to-view-flask-app-on-reserved-static-address-on-google-cloud-platform

Comment: @SHIVANISINGH : Since your issue is resolved can you post the procedure you've followed as a solution and accept it?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is resolved if I add the network tag mentioned here [Unable to view flask app on reserved static address on Google Cloud Platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63069696/unable-to-view-flask-app-on-reserved-static-address-on-google-cloud-platform) in the first step.

Earlier I was incorrectly using the instance name in the "Target tags" field when setting up the firewall rule on GCP.